# ConfigError: No steps directory in 'C:\\Users\\Documents\Automation Framework\\

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, python-behave

I am getting this error when running "behave -f" command, I have **init.py** file in steps,feature folder. Please let me know if there is any solution.

I tried running the feature for generating reports.

Answer (score 0):

this question is not clearly formuled, there are details missing here. You must add something like a capture or similar to show us the directory tree you have in your project or so.

The init.py file doesn't matter to run behave. I'll show you an Hello-World project that works with the proper output of running the command `behave` in the command line.

[image]

If you need some other help, please, add more information about your question.